# QWebEngineView - Load html from resources

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine, qtwidgets

I'm currently playing around with `QWebEngineView` in Qt 5.8 and I would like to load an `index.html` file from my `.qrc` file.

My `.pro` file looks like this:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = Launcher
QT += webenginewidgets
CONFIG += c++14

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += \
    launcher.qrc
```

My `main.cpp` file looks like this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebEngineView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWebEngineView view;
    view.load(QUrl("qrc:/html/index.html"));
    view.resize(1024, 768);
    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

In my project there is a `launcher.qrc` file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/html">
        <file>index.html</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Inside `index.html` I just added the text `Hello World` without anything else.

When I start the application I just get a "Website not reacheable" error screen.
I then googled around and tried several different attempts to specify the resource url to my `QWebEngineView`:

```
view.setUrl(QUrl("qrc:/html/index.html")); // Same error page
view.page()->setUrl(QUrl("qrc:/html/index.html")); // Same error page
view.page()->load(QUrl("qrc:/html/index.html")); // Same error page
```

If I change the resource url from `qrc:/html/index.html` to `:/html/index.html` I don't get this error page anymore but a blank page instead. If I then rightclick the window and select "View page source" the page source is empty, too.

I recently got this working with a fresh Qt Quick Application created with Qt Creator 4.2.2 using the same `qrc:...` url.
Now I created a Qt Widgets Application and it doesn't work anymore.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Works fine for me. Any compile / application output generated indicating anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: Can you try with the most simple website you can think of? <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Heading</h1>

        <p>Something</p>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: It doesn't work regardless of what I put into this file. It seems that the file cannot be found. If I try to open and read the file using QFile and QTextStream the application output says "QIODevice::read (QFile, "qrc:\html\index.html"): device not open".
If I create a new Qt Quick project and use the created .qrc file everything works fine. I don't know why this works and my original Qt Widgets Application does not.

Comment: is the html file located in your folder where the resource file is? also try qrc:///html/index.html what does the full qt += statement look like?

Comment: Yes it is. I have just five files in the source directory: index.html, Launcher.pro, Launcher.pro.user, launcher.qrc and main.cpp. Your suggested url doesn't work too :(

Comment: Forget what I just said. I coincidentally cleaned the project and hit "Run qmake" and then ran the project again. This time it worked with any of the three urls. That's so frustrating.
Thanks for your assistance @deW1

Comment: @TorbenJonas, please put that as an answer. Although it might seem trivial, it could actually save you a lot of time trying to get it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested I will put the solution from the comments above as an answer for future users having the same issue.

"[...] I coincidentally cleaned the project and hit "Run qmake" and then ran the project again. This time it worked with any of the three urls. That's so frustrating.
Thanks for your assistance @deW1"

Comment: Also, `view.load(QUrl(":/html/index.html"));` won't work, it has to have the `qrc:/` protocol.